How to listen to other's app notifications in android while app is terminated?
I'm pretty new to android dev, here is what I'm trying to do :

The app listen to others app notification via a BroadcastReceiver, filter the one I want then do something with the notification data. (I want this to work even when app is killed)

But I can't get it to work, is it even possible ?
I managed to ask the permission BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE but it doesn't work, I'm confused on what I should use between a BroadcastReceiver or NotificationListenerService ... Any help would be lovely :)
I tried different stuff in the manifest as well :
<receiver android:name=".WhatsAppNotificationReceiver"
            android:exported="true" android:enabled="true"  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:label="notifications" android:name=".WhatsAppNotificationReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>```

